# How can I "automatically" get a reminder that day is done?

Tags: macos, applications, reminders, productivity

I many times forget time and stay long hours in the office.
Is there any kind of app that would automatically set a reminder when computer starts + X hours passed?
Now I try to set a reminder (native app) but many times I forget, and it is a bit tedious.
I was wondering if there is somekind of automated way to get some kind of reminder that the day is done?
Has anyone had a similar issue and solved it with some other approach?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the built-in Clock app and add an alarm for the time you want to go home or log off your computer. Select repeat and choose the weekdays that you want it to go off. You can choose a ringtone or song ([We Gotta Get Out Of This Place](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxNEiZhpinY)) instead of one of the standard tones if you want.

The Timer tab in the Clock app can sound an alarm after 8 hours if that's what you want instead.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Basically I was interested in something that does it without me needing to actually set anything. In Windows for example I know that the Computer first start is part of the Events in adminstrator logs and I think it is possible to configure some event on start up. So I was wondering if some kind of event would cause some app (perhaps the clock app that you say) to add to the current time e.g. 8 hours to ring without needing to set it every day manually. Do I make sense I what I describe?

Comment: Where is this timer tab?

Comment: On the bottom of the screen: World Clock - Alarm - Stopwatch -Timer.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't find this build-in Clock app. Is it when I open "Date & Time preferences" when I click on the current time?

Answer (score -1):

You have some great productivity soft like that :

> THE ULTIMATE TIMER. IT'S INSANELY SIMPLE. Toggl’s time tracker is
>   built for speed and ease of use. Time keeping with Toggl is so simple
>   that you’ll actually use it. Toggl drives a stake in the heart of
>   timesheets.

https://toggl.com

> Find your ideal work‑life balance. With so many distractions and
>   possibilities in your digital life, it's easy to get scattered.
>
> RescueTime helps you understand your daily habits so you can focus and
>   be more productive.

https://www.rescuetime.com

> Start putting your time to good use with My Minutes. Wasting too much
>   time browsing the web? Put a cap on your web surfing by setting a goal
>   of "at most 45 minutes".

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-minutes-simple-personal/id553366149?mt=8

**An exhaustive list here :**

http://www.fastcompany.com/3024249/10-time-tracking-apps-that-will-make-you-more-productive-in-2014

Comment: Why is rescue time not in the app store? Is it safe to download and install such way?

Comment: Basically your suggestion is to do time tracking instead I understand

Comment: In my point of view it's safe.. But the tracking is more intrusive... My suggestion was to test a tracking soft and put an alert 'work time done' but i don't really know if it's possible.